# Angular 5 - Barrels for interface and models

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

> Barrels now are far less useful and have been removed from the style
>   guide; they remain valuable but are not a matter of Angular style.
>   Also relaxed the rule that discouraged use of the @Component.host
>   property.

From angular change log, I have understood that barrels are not suggested by Angular. 
So can we use barrels only for models (interface/classes)?

But when I see some links, I came across that some circular dependency issues are there with the barrels in Angular Cli. I don't want to disable the circular dependency.

If I implement barrels only for models, will that give any circular dependency?

https://angular.io/guide/change-log
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/barrel.html

Comment: 1. You can use barrels for whatever, 2. That completely depends on what you create. Pretty vague question. What is your goal in asking this question?

Comment: I want to use barrels. But this is not suggested by Angular team. Based on their changelog, I have understood that the barrels' circular dependency gives issues for component, services, directives, pipes. I hope there is no issue of using barrels with the models (interface/classes). Need to know that can I proceed barrels only with models.

Comment: If you keep it simple, you won't get any circular dependency issues.

Comment: Here's an example of [barrels going bad](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1181#issuecomment-430197191).